# Why to use marshal to dump and pickle to load?

Tags: python, pickle, marshalling

I'm trying to understand the python2 library [remotely](https://pypi.org/project/remotely/) which helps to run code remotely through xmlrpc.

On the client, the author dump the object with marshal and load the result sent back from the server with pickle:

```
def run(self, func, *args, **kwds):
        code_str = base64.b64encode(marshal.dumps(func.func_code))
        output = self.proxy.run(self.api_key, self.a_sync, code_str, *args, **kwds)
        return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(output))
```

And on the server side, he's doing the other way around:

```
def run(self, api_key, a_sync, func_str, *args, **kwds):
        #... truncated code
        code = marshal.loads(base64.b64decode(func_str))
        func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "remote_func")
        #... truncated code
        output = func(*args, **kwds)
        output = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(output))
        return output
```

What's the purpose of dumping with marshal and loading the result with pickle? (and vice-versa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object that is getting sent first using `marshal` is of a very specific type. It's a code object, and only that type needs to be supported. That is a type that the `marshal` module is designed to handle. The return value on the other hand, can be of any type, it's determined by what the `func` function returns. The `pickle` module has a much more general protocol that can serialize many different types of objects, so there's a decent chance it will support the return value.

While you could use `pickle` for both data items being passed between your programs, the `marshal` module's output is a little more compact and efficient for passing code objects, as `pickle` just wraps around it. If you try dumping the same code object with both `marshal` and `pickle` (using protocol zero, the default in Python 2), you'll see the output from `marshal` inside the output from `pickle`!

So to summarize, the `marshal` module is used to sent the code because *only* code objects need to be sent and it's a lower-level serialization, which can be a little more efficient some of the time. The return value is sent back using `pickle` because the program can't predict what type of object it will be, and `pickle` can serialize more complicated values than `marshal` can, at the cost of some additional complexity and (sometimes) the size of the serialization.

Comment: Pickle cannot serialize code objects.  It can serialize a function but only does so by name -- the corresponding function needs to be defined at the receiving end.  So if you want to serialize executable code you have to use marshal for anything else you should probably use pickle.